# Django: Custom Radio Select Layout

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to change the layout of my radio select control to be in the form:

```
<div class="oneitem">
     <label><input type="radio" class="radio" />
     <div>some extra content</div>
</div>
<div class="oneitem">
       .....
</div>
```

I'm trying to write my own renderer:

```
class RandomRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def render(self):
        ret = ''
        for w in self:
            ret += '<div class="oneitem">'
            ret += force_unicode(w)
            ret += '</div>'

        return mark_safe(ret)
```

My question:  in the line

```
for w in self:
```

How do I access the label field and the resultant  field and add 'class="radio'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't need to. The only reason to add a class is to do CSS tricks with it.

Looking at what would be rendered from above:

```
<div class="oneitem">
     <label><input type="radio" />Option's label here</label>
     <div>some extra content</div>
</div>
```

All of your labels can be targeted with `.oneitem label` and all of your radio buttons can be targeted with `.oneitem input` or with extra attributes checks with `.oneitem input[type='radio']`. So the `class='radio'` option would be redundant.